# Opening netbeans via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, netbeans-6.9

I'm very new to netbeans and linux.I'm using netbeans6.9 in my linux OS for Ruby programing. I need to SSH to this machine,through my windows XP laptop and access netbeans.I'm using Cygwin X for the SSH connection.I'm not able to find an answer so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where NetBeans was installed. I have it in `/usr/local/netbeans-6.9/` (I don't know what the default location is, but I don't think this is it), so my executable is `/usr/local/netbeans-6.9/bin/netbeans`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -X <IP> "<path_to_netbeans_binary>"
```