# Opening application via ssh on iOS devices

Tags: ios, jailbreak, launchd, kiosk

I have seen ways to open applications on linux and Mac devices but can't seem to get the same idea working for iOS devices.

I have jailbroken my device and have ssh access and would like to open an app without having to visit the device?

This idea but for iOS and to open a Kiosk app or Safari.

[Opening netbeans via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230300/opening-netbeans-via-ssh)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the `open` utility that's available on the Cydia store.  Download `open` from Cydia, and then you can use it to start any installed app at the command line, using its bundle ID (e.g. **com.mycompany.MyAppName**).

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383664/119114)

Comment: It's worth noting that the package currently available in cydia does not appear to be up to date and working.